Existence of a subregular element with abelian centralizer in a quadratic Lie algebra
All Lie algebras here will be finite dimensionnal complex Lie algebra.
We say that such an Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is quadratic if there exist a skew-symetric, non-degenerate bilinear form or equivalently $\mathfrak{g}$ is quadratic if its adjoint and coadjoint representation are isomorphic. For example, semi-simple Lie algebras are quadratic as per Cartan criterion.
We say that an element $x\in\mathfrak{g}$ is regular if $\dim\mathfrak{g}^x=\min_{y\in\mathfrak{g}}\dim\mathfrak{g}^y$, where $\mathfrak{g}^z$ is the centralizer of $z$ in $\mathfrak{g}$.
We say that an element $x\in\mathfrak{g}$ is subregular if $\dim\mathfrak{g}^x=\min_{y\in\mathfrak{g}}\dim\mathfrak{g}^y+2$. This terminology is not standard but is justified in this case as all centralizers in $\mathfrak{g}$ have the same parity when $\mathfrak{g}$ is quadratic.
My question is : "Is there a quadratic Lie algebra in which there is a subregular element such that its centralizer is abelian ?"
What I know:
-It is not the case among semisimple Lie algebra or reductive Lie algebra.
-The centralizer of an element in a quadratic Lie algebra contain an abelian subalgebra of dimension at least $\min_{y\in\mathfrak{g}}\dim\mathfrak{g}^y$. Hence if the element is subregular, its centralizer is abelian or close to be.
I am also interested in partial results or result droping an hypothesis (complex, quadratic, finite-dimensional).
